# Targeting class inside of class that started script - Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have multiple forms with class `prettyform`. Inside each of those forms is a div `prettydiv`.

I use javascript to catch its submit event like:

```
$(".prettyform").submit(function(e)
```

How can I using above function change `prettydiv` color but only one that is inside form that was submitted.

I know if I'd want to change specific form I can use `$(this)`.

Is there a way to target specific class inside `$(this)` ?

Sorry if it feels like basic question but no google result could give me a good hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).find('.prettydiv').css('color', '#ff0000')
```

Comment: Thank you. Very fast answer. Exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly.